# Grouping values of table elements by id

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I'm making a webpage where one can modify points of players.

Table structure is like this
Contestant (text), Points(input text field with default value current player's points), submit

now, in mysql db every contestant has an id, what i want to do is when someone changes a player's points and clicks submit to be able to relate by id which player got submited. 
This is organized in an html table and i have no clue how to group the data. Anyone can help?

Okay not sure if this is correct, cause i wrote it really fast, but I hope you'll get the idea.

```
$query = "SELECT `con`.`id`, `av`.`name` as `contestant`, `con`.`points` as `points`
          FROM `contestants` as `con`
          JOIN `mydb`.`avatars` as `av`
          WHERE `con`.`boardId`=$id";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die("ERROR:QUERY_FAILED " . mysql_error()); echo "<h4>Boards List</h4><br/>"; 

$numFields = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
            {
                if(mysql_field_name($result,$i) != 'id')
                {
                    echo "<th>";
                        echo mysql_field_name($result,$i);
                    echo "</th>";
                }
            } 
        echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
                for($i = 0; $i < $numFields; $i++)
                {
                    if(mysql_field_name($result, $i) == 'points')
                    {                                       
                        echo "<td><input name='points' type='number' min='0' max='45' value='$row[$i]'></td>";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "<td>$row[$i]</td>";
                    }
                }
                echo "<td>
                    <input type='button' value='Save' onclick='SavePlayersData(this)'>
                    </td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
echo "</table>";
```

What I need is a way to tell to javascript which input field it should process as the players points being saved. hope it makes sense. (btw, there will be more fields than just points. This is just an example.

Comment: Any chance you could add some of your markup/php/sql to your question? There are quite a few ways to go about this task...

Comment: If the player ID is something not seen by the user you could put it in a hidden input within the same form as the associated Points input: `<input type="hidden" name="playerID" value="123">` - the value would be set within your PHP code (as you presumably already do for the Contestant field).

Comment: @nnnnnn I've thought of that, but the problem is that i'm doing this with a table and I'm not sure how to combine form and table rows.
Is  
    <table>
        <form>
            <tr>
                <td>something</td> 
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something</td>
            </tr>
    </form> 
        <form>
            <tr>
                <td>something</td> 
                <td>something</td>
                <td>something</td>
            </tr>
    </form> 
</table>doable?

Comment: You can have `<form>` elements as children of `<td>` elements, but not directly under `<table>` or `<tr>`. Does `SavePlayersData()` use Ajax to submit - if so you don't need forms within your table. Or you could put the whole table in a form, and have a single save button that submits the values for all players at once.

Comment: Yes, I'm using AJAX. But how could I group them without a form and without submiting all values for all players? And how could I group them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your form fields with values like "player1_points", "player2_points", etc.  On the server, loop through all values received, looking for these fields.  Welcome to 1993.

EDIT: get thyself a toolkit, like extjs, which handles all this nonsense (and much more) automatically.  ext4js is a huge improvement over previous versions.

Comment: I've thought of looping through names, and manipulating the string to see which is which with the number inside the name. The thing is that I don't want to be welcomed to 1993... I want something 2012ish, Ajax wasn't there in 93 I think. There must be another way to group the data, real grouping, not workaround. If not, and you're sure, pls let me know.

Comment: I think I first saw "ajax" in 1994 or 1995.  Anyway, naming your fields uniquely is the right way to do it, and it's how toolkits like extjs do it (and they hide all that from you, and more!).

Comment: Well since I didn't find anything else. I can't do something else. Ty